# Is there a way to use the java browsing perspective of eclipse for python?

Tags: python, eclipse, perspective

I'd like to use the browsing perspective ("column view") of eclipse for Python development. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

please look http://www.pydev.org

Comment: there's nothing there about the browsing perspective, and I already have pydev installed. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I think you need to configure your project, change your perspective to pydev python perspective from Menu, and also check whether you've configured "source folder" under eclipse project properties.